# Can't delete all cards that were created by forEach

Tags: javascript

This forEach loop creates html elements (cards) when user click the button but if user click the button again all cards supposedly must be deleted. In my case when I click the button again only the first card is gone. I know that it smth has to do with id. I tried to do this () but I have no idea what to do next to delete all cards. thanks for attention

```js
function getFood(){
    if (foodBtn.classList.contains("yes")){
        fetch("http://localhost:1314/getByType/food")
            .then((resp => {
                return resp.json();
            }))
            .then((resp) => {
                resp.forEach(elem => {
                    div.innerHTML += `<div id="MyFood">
               <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <img src="${elem.image}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <b>price: ${elem.price} $</b>
                     <p class="card-text">description: ${elem.description}</p>
                     <p class="card-text">amount: ${elem.amount}</p>
                    </div>
               </div>
               </div>`
                })
            })
        foodBtn.classList.remove("yes");
        foodBtn.classList.add("no");
    }else {
         const q = document.getElementById('MyFood');
         console.log(q);
         q.innerHTML = "";

        foodBtn.classList.remove("no");
        foodBtn.classList.add("yes");
    }
}
```

Comment: You inserted a runnable snippet that is not-so-runnable yet (does nothing).  It would be best if clicking "run code snippet" demonstrated the issue.

Comment: Multiple HTML elements may not share the same ID. Use classes instead. Also, you don't delete an HTML element with `innerHTML`. You do `element.remove()`.

Comment: ids need to be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indeed right. In html IDs are unique so using the same ID for multiple instances may not work as expected. The solution is either add something in the generation that would create unique IDs such as

```
resp.forEach((elem, index) => {
                div.innerHTML += `<div id="MyFood${index}">
           <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img src="${elem.image}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                <b>price: ${elem.price} $</b>
                 <p class="card-text">description: ${elem.description}      </p>
                 <p class="card-text">amount: ${elem.amount}</p>
                </div>
           </div>
           </div>`
            })
```

or use a class instead of an ID (I would personally go with this)

```
resp.forEach(elem => {
                div.innerHTML += `<div class="MyFood">
           <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img src="${elem.image}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                <b>price: ${elem.price} $</b>
                 <p class="card-text">description: ${elem.description}</p>
                 <p class="card-text">amount: ${elem.amount}</p>
                </div>
           </div>
           </div>`
            })
```

Then to select and delete just call

```
const q = document.querySelectorAll('.MyFood');
for (let i = 0; i < q; i++) {
   q[i].remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple HTML elements may not share the same ID. That's why when you try to select `#MyFood` you're only getting one. Instead, you can change it to classes, which are sort of like IDs for multiple elements. In `div.innerHTML += ...`, change the first part of the string from `<div id="MyFood" ...` to `<div class="MyFood" ...`, then in your `else` you need to change the selector to classes:

```js
const elements = [...document.getElementsByClassName("MyFood")]; // you can also do: [...document.querySelectorAll(".MyFood")]
elements.forEach(el => el.remove()); // loop through array of elements and remove each one
// ...
```

Learn more about the selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly an `id` issue. If multiple HTML elements share the same `id`, when you call `getElementById()` only the first element with that id will get called. To fix this without changing much of your code, you instead of using `id` you can try setting `class="MyFood"` then call `getElementsByClassName()` method.

A different approach, if for some reason you need the `id="MyFood"` element to appear in your code, is to wrap all your cards inside a `div` like this:

```
<div id="MyFood">
  ...cards here
</div>
```

then the rest of your code will work without changing anything.